# Codeigniter Bonfire install using AMPPS on MAC OSX 10.93 gives 404

Tags: codeigniter, bonfire

I am trying to install Bonfire for Codeigniter on my Mac OSX 10.93 (Mavericks) and it shows the welcome screen and then when I click on the continue button to install it, I get a 404 error.

It goes to this URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/<?=%20$install_url%20?>
```

It works find on my server, so does anyone know if there is something I have to configure differently to make it work on my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very easy go to this url directly from browser **`http://mydomain.com/public/`** also before install config your db info to **`YOUR_APPLICATION_PATH/application/config/database.php`**